# Create Cals table

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i've the below XML document, where some cals table has to be created.

```
<table frame="none">
    <tgroup cols="5" align="left" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
        <colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c1"/>
        <colspec colwidth="70pt" colname="c2"/>
        <colspec colwidth="10pt" colname="c3"/>
        <colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c4"/>
        <colspec colwidth="75pt" colname="c5"/>
        <thead>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>Item</para>
                </entry>
                <entry align="center">
                    <para>Injury</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Percentage of loss of earning capacity</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>1.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of 2 limbs ...................................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="7">
                    <para>}</para>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="7">
                    <para>100</para>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="7">
                    <para></para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>2.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of both hands or of all fingers and both thumbs ...</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>3.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of both feet ................................................................</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>4.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Total loss of sight ...............................................................</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>5.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Total paralysis ....................................................................</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>6.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Injuries resulting in being permanently bedridden .......</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>7.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Paraplegia ..........................................................................</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>8.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Any other injury causing permanent total disablement ...</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>9.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of arm at shoulder ....................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>75</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>80 (preferred hand)</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>10.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Ankylosis of shoulder joint—</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>in optimum position .....................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>35</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>in worst position ............................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>55</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>11.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of arm between elbow and shoulder .......................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>75</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>80 (preferred hand)</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>12.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Loss of arm at elbow ..........................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>75</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>80 (preferred hand)</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>13.</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>Ankylosis of the elbow joint—</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>in optimum position .....................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>30</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>in worst position ............................................................</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>50</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para/>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <para>14.</para>
                </entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

here i've to create a table as shown in the below picture [image]

i know its not a good idea to ask for code directly, i tried for normal tables(which were done), but i'm really unable to know how to do a cals table in xslt. please let me know how i can achieve doing these cals table.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than a picture of how it would render, it would be much more useful if you could show the actual XML you're trying to generate.

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts, thanks for responding, here actually i don't have any xml output to be generated, i need to convert this xml into a HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in a comment that you're looking for HTML output - well the input XML you're starting with has the right structure to convert directly into an HTML table with a 1-1 mapping of element names, you just need to turn the `morerows="n"` of the source format into a `rowspan="n+1"` in the HTML

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <!-- these nodes have the same names in HTML -->
  <xsl:template match="table | thead | tbody">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- row becomes tr -->
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates /></tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- entry becomes td -->
  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="@morerows|node()" /></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry/@morerows">
    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan" select="1 + ." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We rely here on the default template rules for nodes that don't have an explicit template, which will process children recursively in the case of elements and output the text in the case of text nodes.

You've tagged the question XSLT 2.0 but for the record this is almost an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, the only thing you'd have to change is that `xsl:attribute` doesn't take a `select` in 1.0, so instead of `<xsl:attribute name="rowspan" select="..." />` you'd need `<xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="..." /></xsl:attribute>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ian, here i find somewhere in my xmls like colend, colest, can you please explain how i can catch them and what do they represent? Thanks

Comment: @user2423959 I'm not that familiar with docbook (I presume this input is docbook), if you have a specific example of this case and what you need to transform it into, then feel free to ask it as a separate Stack Overflow question.